# Where does TortoiseSVN save password cached files in Windows 7?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Where does TortoiseSVN save password cached files in Windows 7?

I found `c:\users\USERNAME\AppData\TSVNCache` directory, but it is empty.

Comment: Tortoise 1.9.4 does not seem to save authentication properly. At least for me (Windows 7). Rolling back to version 1.8.12 and everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In `c:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\`.

Comment: Yes, by default all users of the subversion api (read: most subversion clients) store their settings in %appdata%\Subversion. The passwords are stored in the auth directory below that directory.

TortoiseSVN has a clear authentication data button on its 'Saved Data' settings tab (TortoiseSvn->Settings). AnkhSVN has an option to delete only authentication token for a specific server.

Comment: @BertHuijben, this comment is the right answer really!

Answer (score 27):

> %APPDATA%\Subversion\auth

It is documented in the TortoiseSVN Help document file (CHM)

Answer (score 7):

In Windows, there is an option (in TortoiseSVN → *Settings* → *Saved Data* → *Authentication Data*) to clear stored credentials in the last version.

TortoiseSVN is just the client, and if you want to add/change/delete/manage users and authentication for the SVN repositories, you have to run the SVN Server program. If you don't know where it is, it should be in your Start → *Programs* menu. If not there, it should be running as a Windows service you can find in *Control Panel* → *Services*. If not there, it could be found in `C:/Program Files`.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows 7 - Remove the auth folder from

```
c:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\
```

and when you access the SVN repository again you will be asked for the username and password.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows XP, it's stored at

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<<username>>\Application Data\Subversion\auth
```

Remove the `auth` folder, and when you access the SVN repository again you will be asked for the username and password.

Answer (score 3):

For most Linux distributions it's

```
~/.subversion/auth/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) file/registry access watch tool to find out for sure.

> [DiskMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896646.aspx) is an application that logs
>   and displays all hard disk activity on
>   a Windows system. You can also
>   minimize DiskMon to your system tray
>   where it acts as a disk light,
>   presenting a green icon when there is
>   disk-read activity and a red icon when
>   there is disk-write activity.
>
> [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) is an advanced
>   monitoring tool for Windows that shows
>   real-time file system, Registry and
>   process/thread activity. It combines
>   the features of two legacy
>   Sysinternals utilities, Filemon and
>   Regmon, and adds an extensive list of
>   enhancements including rich and
>   non-destructive filtering,
>   comprehensive event properties such
>   session IDs and user names, reliable
>   process information, full thread
>   stacks with integrated symbol support
>   for each operation, simultaneous
>   logging to a file, and much more. Its
>   uniquely powerful features will make
>   Process Monitor a core utility in your
>   system troubleshooting and malware
>   hunting toolkit.

Start these applications and create a new checkout of any passworded repository.