# TortoiseSVN not saving authentication details

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN is not saving my authentication details even when I check the save authentication checkbox, and asking me to enter username and password every time I access it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hey, maybe you could mark the answer as 'accepted'?

Answer (score 81):

I had the same issue and I simply deleted this folder:

```
%APPDATA%\subversion\auth\
```

Next time I logged in it was created anew and my password was properly saved.

Comment: yeah after I changed the password I had to delete the mentioned dir to make toroisesvn to save the new password

Comment: This did not work for SourceForge. It keeps asking me for a password.

Answer (score 58):

If you access your repo over `ssh`, then you can use the following solution to save your `ssh` credentials:

> The easiest way to do this is to right click in Windows Explorer,
>   select Tortoise > Settings. Then in the Settings window select
>   Network. Then in the SSH client set use the Tortoise SSH client,
>   TortoisePlink, to use your username and password. For example:
>
> ```
> [DRIVE LETTER]:\[DIR]\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe -l foo -pw bar
> ```
>
> [source](http://betweengo.com/2006/10/30/howto-stop-being-prompted-for-password-in-tortoisesvn/)

For instance, mine is

```
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe -l *mysvnusername* -pw *mysvnpassword*
```

I have tried this and TortoiseSVN does not ask you for password for update or commit anymore. It is slightly insecure, since your ssh password is stored in plain text.

Comment: If tortoise tries to put quotes around the whole thing, remove the quotes.

Comment: Although this is way less hassle because you don't have to have an external process running in the background, it's probably worth nothing though that if you use more than one repository regularly with different usernames/passwords, you might have to go the pageant way instead.

Comment: If you do have spaces in the path and you need to use quotes then have them just around the path: "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe" -l mysvnusername -pw mysvnpassword

Comment: Thank you! Worked great for 1.8 on Win 7 64 bit

Comment: It is far more secure to set up an identity file, and authenticate using that instead of a password.

Comment: Works for me.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 20):

If you're using `svn+ssh://` to access your repository, svn isn't involved in authentication at all so it simply can not save the authentication. In that case, you have to use an SSH tool like `pageant` to store your authentication data.

Comment: It's a little burdensome. This link from tortoise's site is a general approach: http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto.html , in particular, if you are using sourceforge, follow this instructions https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/community-docs/TortoiseSVN/ . Basically it involves creating a ssh key with puttygen, uploading the public key to the ssh server and then using pageant to load the private key. Note that you got to have pageant running everytime you use tortoise (you might consider adding it to the windows startup)

Comment: The link to the instructions at SourceForge is dead, and I can't find their replacement using Google.

Answer (score 16):

Here is what worked for me: in TortoiseSVN > Settings > Saved Data, click the Clear button near Authentication Data.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me too. Tortoise cached the authentication data and deleting %APPDATA%\subversion\auth\ did not have any effect! Thanks a LOT.

Answer (score 6):

Considering TortoiseSVN save the authentication informations in the:

```
# WindowsXp
"%APPDATA%"\subversion\auth
# or, for Windows7
"%APPDATA%"\Roaming\Subversion\auth
```

(see [Where does TortoiseSVN save password cached files in Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598510/where-does-tortoisesvn-save-password-cached-files-in-windows-7))

You could check if you have any right issue in those directories (try to create a file in it).
Maybe another process block the access to the right authentication file: try rebooting, and see if the problem persist.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Tortoise Settings > Saved Data > Authentication Data 
And clear whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on Windows 7. Just remove the following directory and restart TortoiseSVN: C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue...

Had to add the following to my `%APPDATA%\subversion\servers`

store-passwords = yes

( i also added 
store-auth-creds = yes
store-plaintext-passwords = yes
for good measure)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the easiest/best way to do this is check out the repository using a URL like:

```
svn+ssh://userid@host.com/path/to/repo
```

Putting the user name in there makes TortiseSVN/Plink use it in the future automatically. Combined with Pageant, you don't have to worry about anything. And it's not global so you can have different user names for different repositories.

Answer (score 0):

If you have applications programmatically accessing Subversion, for instance via SharpSVN or SVNKit, your local authentication cache could be getting modified.

There's a simple fix for this--uncomment the following line in Subversion's local config file

`store-auth-creds = no`

This file is usually stored within the 'Application Data' directory. (Which is a hidden directory by default--unhide hidden folders in folder options). In XP and depending on your installation, this directory is usually at

> C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Subversion

If this config file is not available in your version of TortoiseSVN you have to configure the same setting in the 'servers' file (within the same directory) as a group-based authentication setting. Portions of the config file have been deprecated since my build. My group is using TortoiseSVN 1.6.0, Build 15855.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I used ssh to connect `TortoiseSVN` to a `local Linux Server` without logging in:

**1. Setup (not sure if this section is necessary)**

1.1.    Open `TortoiseSVN settings` (Right click a file, tortoiseSVN > Settings)

1.2.    In the `settings`, select `Network`

1.3.    Under SSH, `SSH client`, enter: `"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe"`

1.4.    Click `OK`.

1.5.    Install putty

**2. Generate the keys**

2.1.    Run `“C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\puttygen.exe”`

2.2.    Select `ssh-2 rsa`

2.3.    Click `Generate` (move the cursor around in the window to generate the key)

2.4.    Move the cursor around until it is complete (the completion bar should fill up completely)

2.5.    Add a key comment (description or user name)

2.6.    Select `Save public key`

2.7.    Save it to a file that you create (example: Documents > ssh > description-public-key)

2.8.    Select `Save private key`

2.9.    Save it to a file that you create (example: Documents > ssh > description-private-key)

2.10.   Select and `copy the key` from the window

2.11.   Save it to a file that you create (example: Documents > ssh > `description-authorized-key.txt`)

**3. Set up the server side**

3.1.    Putty to the server and `log in as the user`

3.2.    In the home directory, go to or make .ssh (`~/.ssh`)

3.3.    Open/make authorized_keys (`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`)

3.4.    `Copy the text` from the putty gen window that was saved in the `description-authorized-key.txt`

3.5.    `Paste the text` in the `authorized_keys` file

3.6.    Save and exit

3.7.    `chmod 600 authorized_keys`

3.9.    Make sure that the `subversion server is running` (To check: `ps -e | grep svnserve`, to launch: `svnserve -d`)

3.8.    end the putty session

**4. Set up the client side**

4.1.    `Open putty` on the client/Windows/TortoiseSVN side

4.2.    Go to `Connection` > `SSH` > `Auth`

4.3.    In `Private key file for authentication`, `enter the full path` to the description-private-key file (example: `C:\Users\<user name>\Documents\ssh\description-private-key.ppk`)

4.4.    Go to `Session`

4.5.    Under `Saved Sessions`, select `Default Settings`

4.6.    With Default Settings selected, select `save`

4.7.    *Firewalls might need to be disabled or given exceptions*

4.8.    Go to a directory to put an SVN checkout (right click > `SVN Checkout...`)

4.9.    In the `URL of repository`, use `svn+ssh://username@...` (example: `svn+ssh://jdoe@172.217.0.4/path/to/repo`)

**References:**

http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-with-putty/

https://kb.wisc.edu/education/page.php?id=45394

https://kb.wisc.edu/education/page.php?id=45394

https://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2356647/5582694

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved the issue in my laptop.
Open %APPDATA%\Roaming\subversion\servers file in notepad
Towards the end of the file there is a section that had the following:
store-password = no
I changed it to yes.