# TortoiseSVN not saving auth details when accessing a server via ssh

Tags: svn, ssh, tortoisesvn

TortoiseSVN is not saving my auth details even when I access to a remote server using svn+ssh. For some reason it's asking me to enter username and password every time I access it.

How can I fix this.
Thanks.

Note that this question is slighty related to [TortoiseSVN not saving authentication details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048718/tortoisesvn-not-saving-auth-details) 
which was not awnsered.

The only awnser that might help was about using pageant, which I haven't found a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseSVN simply **can not** save the auth details, because it never even sees them!

But since you're using SSH, you can use SSHs own tools to store the auth details. As explained [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto.html), you can use `pageant` for this.