# How to force TortoiseSVN client 1.11.1 on Win10 to prompt for credentials (disable automatic LDAP authentication)?

Tags: authentication, svn, tortoisesvn

I've just installed latest TortoiseSVN client on Win 10 Pro v1803 b17134.556
I've done pretty much default installation, with possible only alteration that I wanted also CLI client. So it's in MS Win 10 default path: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\TortoiseSVN`

```
1.11.1, Build 28492 - 64 Bit , 2019/01/08 21:40:39
ipv6 enabled
Subversion 1.11.1, -release
apr 1.6.5
apr-util 1.6.1
serf 1.3.9
OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018
zlib 1.2.11
SQLite 3.23.1
```

And obviously tried to browse and checkout an SVN repository.
A colleague of mine has TortoiseSVN client v1.9.5.xxx and he can browse our SVN server "nzchch-svn-yyy.xxxxxx.zzzzz.net/svn/MGIS without any issues. He can't remember how he managed to authenticate himself a long time ago, but he doesn't need to authenticated (I mean provide credentials) these days.
However I would expect kind of [authentication dialog](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug.html#tsvn-dug-general-auth) to pop up for me. Instead of it I'm getting only:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL
'https://..........net/svn/MGIS
Access to '/svn/MGIS' forbidden
```

I'm not sure if it is authenticated against LDAP, but even though if it does and my LDAP account doesn't have permission to access it (which I think is the case), I do have available a service account we use on Jenkins server to checkout the SVN repo, and I should be able to provide those credentials somehow. But Tortoise doesn't ask me for the credentials at all.

I tried to authenticate via CMD, running:

```
svn auth --username jenkinsuser --password topsecret
Credentials cache in 'C:\Users\bfu\AppData\Roaming\Subversion' is empty
```

I tried to follow several advices like:

- [remove auth dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048718/tortoisesvn-not-saving-authentication-details/5769231):

  `rmdir /S %APPDATA%\subversion\auth\%APPDATA%\subversion\auth`
- Clearing 'All my Saved Data', well as it is a clean install I have enabled on to Clear: URL history and Dialog Sizes and positions.
- Updating the config file to enable:

  `password-stores = windows-cryptoapi
  store-passwords = yes
  store-auth-creds = yes`

which was commented out.

Just no way I can provide credentials and if it comes down, I can use hundreds of SVN servers with different authentication data and no way to enable it or force it to ask me for it.

Any idea what is going on? I'm pretty hopeless as I couldn't imagine there would be a such stubborn SVN client which would refused to ask me for credentials (and possibly save it in the next step).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with authentication, but with authorization. Your user account does not have permissions to access MGIS repository. You need to review and fix your permissions.

Read https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/#User-Permissions.

Comment: Yes, you're right and now it has been fixed.

However, I was expecting, I would be able to provide other credentials what I have available - of the service account which is used by our build server to checkout src from the SVN server.

Comment: In other words, I was seeking how to checkout or browse SVN repositories with credentials I have available, not associated with my LDAP account.

Perhaps I should reword a bit my question...

Comment: In TortoiseSVN, if  you want to use a different ID than the one your have stored, you have to clear out the stored credentials.  `TortoiseSVN > Settings > Saved Data`.  From this window click the `Clear...` option to the right of Authentication Data.

Comment: Thanks @David, I tried this, but it didn't have stored anything. It was clear new install and my own LDAP (Win domain) account was not allowed to access it.
Hence I was wanting to use our "service account" which I couldn't entered.

I've already gained access to the repository/server, but still it would be great to know how to use different credentials.